# Error: Undefined data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function to fetch new ads in every 10 seconds, but im getting the error

```
function getnewads(){
    var newer ;
    // This fetches old value from 'data-value' attribute
    var old_val = $("#new_data").data('value');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "users/process.php",
        data:{
            getnewads: "getnewads"
        },
        cache: false ,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
    }).success(function(dat){
        if(dat.status == 'success'){
            $("#new_data").empty();
            for(i = 0;i < dat.counts; i++){
                newer = dat.counts + old_val; alert(old_val); /// problem att old_val alerts Object object.
                if(newer > 0){
                    $("#new_data").html('<div class="added_ad">'+ newer +' new ads </div>');
                    // This set 'data-value' attribute to #new_data element
                    $("#new_data").data('value',newer);
                    $("#new_data").show();
                }else{$("#new_data").hide();$("#new_data").data('value',0);}
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my html div

```
 <div id="new_data" class="new_data">
 </div>
```

I have tested everything works just this `old_val` is alerting `Object object`
What am I doing wrong ?
thanks

If I alert `old_val` it shows `Object object`

If I alert `old_val.val()` its shows `undefined old_val`

Comment: try to log to ur console, most browsers can access the whole object in a treeview with all params in it like `console.log(dat)` also known issue on some browsers is that they cant access DOM with the `.data()` func of jQuery, use `.attr("data-"+yourdata)` instead

Comment: You probably are setting and object to `data-value` attribute at first time.

Comment: Every 10 seconds?! Mobile users will not like having their data plan drained dry!

Comment: `$("#new_data").data('value')` *should* return `undefined` if the attribute is not set or no value is found in the global data collection. Did you try consoling/alerting this?

Comment: @UnskilledFreak How u mean ? like that ? `var old_val = $("#new_data").attr("data-"+value)`

Comment: "async: false" Bad idea

Comment: @David yes as you see in my code i alerted it.

Comment: @epascarello why Bad idea ? should i do it true ?

Comment: No, you alerted `old_val`. Try alerting the data attribute

Comment: @ScooterDaraf yes, in ur case it'll be `var old_val = $("#new_data").attr('data-value');`

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Nice it worked with your suggest , it alerts now 0 thanks so much :) . if you want add it as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @UnskilledFreak and this ? `$("#new_data").data('value',0);` in my last code how it should be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.attr()` instead of `.data()`

there are known issues with incompatible browsers on `.data()`

change your code to

```
var old_val = $("#new_data").attr('data-value');
```

to get the val from the object.

Notice: `.attr()` is get and set, if u want to set a val to this obj use

```
$("#new_data").attr('data-value',newvalue);
```